# Netbeans 7.2.1 mac javadoc not found Java Me

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, javadoc

For some reason Netbeans can't access javadoc in Java ME projects.
Netbeans does find javadoc in Java Desktop Application

Attached an image of my Java ME javadoc.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: did you add those jar files yourself or do they come from the netbeans install? do they actually contain javadoc information or just .class files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an alternative to those jar files, you might want to download the specifications directly from the JCP website at http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/all then add the javadoc they contain to Netbeans.

The relevant JSRs should be 139 and 118.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your `.../doc` path is not empty and the other files are existing? if there's a java doc in html form you can make a zip/jar and add it then.

Also make shure that your path is complete:

```
jar:file:/<your path here>/yourdoc.jar!/docs/api/
```

*where `/docs/api` is the path insde the archive*

But if this doesn't work the better solution is **adding the url of the online javadoc** instead of a file.